# Python multiprocessing.Queue not receiving puts from forked processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, fork

I am creating a fixed number of forked child processes and attempting to have them return a result via `multiprocessing.Queue`. This is leading to some unexpected behaviour.

```
import multiprocessing
import os

def main():
    n_workers = 4

    q = multiprocessing.Queue(n_workers)

    for i in range(n_workers):
        if os.fork() == 0:
            print(f"child {i} put {i}")
            q.put(i)
            print(f"child {i} exiting")
            os._exit(0)

    for i in range(n_workers):
        res = q.get()
        print(f"parent got {res}")

    print("parent exiting")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run this, all of the children enqueue their results and terminate, but the parent process hangs:

```
child 0 put 0                                                                              │
child 1 put 1                                                                              │
child 2 put 2                                                                              │
child 3 put 3                                                                              │
child 0 exiting                                                                            │
child 1 exiting                                                                            │
child 2 exiting                                                                            │
child 3 exiting                                                                            │
parent got 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `os._exit(0)` call immediately after putting data into the queue.

The [multiprocessing docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) explain how data is added to the queue:

> When an object is put on a queue, the object is pickled and a background thread later flushes the pickled data to an underlying pipe.

Because the process is forked, the call to `os._exit(0)` is necessary (as opposed to `sys.exit(0)`), but it [does not do any cleanup](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os._exit). If the background thread has not yet flushed the data, it will be lost!

The solution is to call `close()` followed by `join_thread()`:

```
import multiprocessing
import os

def main():
    n_workers = 4

    q = multiprocessing.Queue(n_workers)

    for i in range(n_workers):
        if os.fork() == 0:
            print(f"child {i} put {i}")
            q.put(i)
            print(f"child {i} exiting")

            q.close()  # indicate nothing else will be queued by this process
            q.join_thread()  # wait for the background thread to flush the data

            os._exit(0)

    for i in range(n_workers):
        res = q.get()
        print(f"parent got {res}")

    print("parent exiting")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```